# Python walk thourgh 2D data (scatter plot)= and count points in diamond shape until reaching boundary

Tags: python, scatter

I am kind of stucking here, I have a rectangular 2D domain (see scatter plots). In order to parallelize my task I need to ensure the right number of mpi processes. Therefore I created a scatter plot matrix with start point in the middle (latter on needs to be near the center of the scatter plot) of the domain.

Next I want to find the maximal number of MPI Processes (scatter points) until my boundary on left, up, down or right is reached. The number of scatter points, reaching first my boundary are limiting the number of processors.
For clearification I attached a picture:
[image]

Next, i started with this code:

```
job_rest=num_Re*num_alpha
border = Re_start +alpha_start*1j
num_border=1
border_update=[]

while job_rest != 0:

    border_right=(np.real(border)+1)+np.imag(border)*1j
    border_left=(np.real(border)-1)+np.imag(border)*1j
    border_up=(np.real(border))+(np.imag(border)+1)*1j
    border_down=(np.real(border))+(np.imag(border)-11)*1j

    border = border_update
    num_border = border.size
    job_rest = job_rest - num_border
```

Next I want to implement if then else conditions for reaching boundary and updating the `num_border` size.

So is there a more elegant or smart way obtaining the limiting mpi processes by boundaries?

Comment: I don't undersand the question ... Is it a question about geometry or something totally different ? I have no idea what a "MPI process" is, and is it even relevant to the problem ?

Comment: I am sorry, each scatter point represents an MPI Process or a CPU in physical. This is just kind of an abstraction of parallelization.

Comment: So you can reduce my MPI problem to a simple scatter plot, where each scatter point represents one calculating task. In order to obtain the most efficient numbers of mpi processes, i need just get the number of selected scatter points when one of the boundarys is reached

Comment: for process i,j of grid n,m, half diagonal of the diamond is or length `a=min(i,j,n-i-1,m-j-1)`. Then, the number of processes on the edge of the diamond is `l=4*a`.